# MySQL update varchar value using old value plus a new string

Tags: mysql, string, concatenation

I have a bunch of image references in a table like:

```
data/fabrics/signature/signature1.jpg
data/fabrics/signature/signature2.jpg
```

And I need to go through the table and add an additional folder to the image path like:

```
data/group1/fabrics/signature/signature1.jpg
data/group1/fabrics/signature/signature2.jpg
```

Is there any way to do this with just MySQL queries, or will I need to use PHP to concatenate the strings and then update the database?

Comment: There sure is. Have you had a look at the mysql documentation? It contains a set of string functions you can use for this.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a simple replacement function, replacing the beginning of the string with a different beginning. Probably the easiest solution if the replacements are so simple.

```
UPDATE tbl SET col=REPLACE(col, 'data/fabrics', 'data/group1/fabrics') WHERE xxx;
```

You might have to run several of these, depending on the specific replacements needed, with different `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: I beg your pardon? What's wrong with my statement? It will add an additional folder into the image page. The precise search/replace terms might be changed, so `data/` could be replaced with `data/group1/` if that's valid for all of them. The way I wrote it demonstrates that you could put `fabrics` in `group1` and `booze` in `group2` or similar. Or am I still missing something?

Comment: I did not edit the statement at all. I just put changed the font of the `WHERE` in the text.

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly. I really appreciate the answer.

Comment: How can I "accept" this answer? Or is there such a thing around here?

Comment: Beneath the answers vote count on the left (currently 0) there should be a checkmark outline. When you click that, it becomes green and marks this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
update table1
set link=substring(link,1,charindex('/',link,1))+
         'group1'+substring(link,charindex('/',link,1),LEN(link))
where (your condition)
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/efd0b/2)**